# Ubuntu slow and laggy

Tags: drivers, video

I finally installed Ubuntu 14.04 (from a boot CD) but everything seems so slow.
It takes a few seconds to open a window or to close a window, like if everything was in slow motion. When I type a text in any field, specially from the launcher, the characters appear on the monitor much slower than I type them.
I know I have little memory, but it is still too slow. 
I read about updating video drivers, but I don't know how to upgrade them as there no new "recommended" ones.

Here is what I have:

- Memory 985.0 MiB
- Intel® Pentium(R) M processor 1.70GHz
- Graphics
  VESA: Intel(r)852GM/852GME/855GM/855GME
- 32 bit OS
- 40G HDD
  The PC is a Inspiron 710m laptop.

Any advice would be appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: From your processor specs I would guess that you would be much happier running Lubuntu.  You can make a halfway shift to that by installing LXDE (the Lubuntu desktop) to try it out `sudo apt-get install lxde`  Then logout, choose lxde as the environment and log back in.

Comment: Upgrade your memory, in my opinion it's just a memory problem :)

Comment: Try `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

Comment: Your RAM is too low for Ubuntu. As many people suggest here, you will probably happy with **Lubuntu**. See comparison between Linux desktop user interface here so you can choose the best for your machine: 1) http://l3net.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/a-memory-comparison-of-light-linux-desktops/ 2) http://l3net.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/ubuntu-desktop-memory-comparison/. Read both and you will know why people suggest you to choose Lubuntu.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I tried to upgrade the memory but since the PC is old, the one I got was not compatible, so I installed Lubuntu and now it is a huge difference in performance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using lubuntu distro you are currently using Unity Desktop which requires much higher hardware Configuration. So, in my opinion you should try installing `lubuntu`

You can get more details and download it [here](http://lubuntu.net/)
also as you have a slow system and very little space I also recommend you to download Lubuntu from other system and make a live usb from that system (usually windows system) and then install it in your system.

[pendrive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) linux and [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-lubuntu-on-a-flash-drive-using-windows/) link will help you with installation

Answer (score 0):

The hardware specs are low, you'd be better with lubuntu or xubuntu. But you can remove fancy effects from unity as well. Browse the software center for Unity Tweak and install it. Remove transparencies, active blur from dash and so on. That may help.